# Regex to describe binary numbers

Tags: regex, binary

I want to have a regular expression to describe all binary numbers (consisting only of 0 and 1).

So it should work for 100 0 101001 11 000
but not for the 1 and 0 parts in hello1001and011. It really should only match to all digit numbers.

I wanted to write ^(0|1)(0|1)*(0|1)$ to mark that it should begin and end with a zero or one and in the middle can be arbitrary many 0 and 1 but it doesn't match anything.

In my lecture we just saw operations like | , + , * , ^ , $ , . , as well as \d and \w.

Can someone please help me to find my error/give me a working regular expression?

Comment: "but **IT** doesn't match anything" What is **IT**? How did you test the epxression? The posted expression matches all binary numbers with atleast 2 digits. If you wanted to match also "1" and "0" then `(0|1)+` should work. Also there are plenty of regex testing/debugging websites e.g. regex101.com

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use word boundaries `\b`:

```
\b[01]+\b
```

In your regex you're using `^` (beginning of line or text) and `$` (end of line or text), which means it tries to match the whole string, rather than matching separate words/numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
[0*1*]*[1*0*]*
```

Hope this helps and it passes every binary number.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it only contains `1` or `0`, `n` times:

```java
[0-1]+
```

[image: regex description]
src: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

If the given sting is a binary number, it will return true.
   Otherwise, it will return false.

```js
const str1 = '10101';
const str2 = '1002s1';
const regex = new RegExp('^[0-1]{1,}$','g');

console.log(regex.test(str1));
console.log(regex.test(str2));
```